# Global SASS variables in reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, sass

Im currently learning reactjs and Ive just added SASS to my project. However, I want to create a single file that stores all my variables and mixins globally that can then be used by any other scss file in my project. How is this possible without having to manually import the file into every scss file that i make?

My folder structure:

/src
    assets/
        images/

```
components/
    app/
        app.js
        app.scss

styles/
    scss/
        main.scss
        _var.scss
        _mixins.scss
        _typography.scss

index.css
index.js
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to import your variables at the top of a master import file, with all other imports coming after.  So, assuming your directory structure above, in `main.scss` you'd want to do:

```
@import 'var';
@import 'mixins';
@import 'typography';

...

// Component imports
@import '../../components/app/app';
```

Alternatively, you could set up a shared master import file somewhere closer to the base of your project (say, `index.scss`), which would then look like:

```
// in `styles/scss/main.scss`
@import 'var';
@import 'mixins';
@import 'etc';

// in `index.scss`
// Base style import
@import 'styles/scss/main.scss';

// Component imports
@import 'components/app/app';
@import 'components/etc/etc';
```

The important factor here is that you need to be importing anything that needs access to your shared variables *after* your variable import.  Otherwise the variables won't be in scope.

Comment: my main.scss file gets imported into the root component (app). however, when i try this method and import my components into that file it doesnt detect the variables still. styles are caught and used, by anything that relys on a var outside the main,scss file still breaks